# ORA 06502 error when called inside procedure but when executed using test window it works well

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dblink

I'm invoking a procedure schema1.proc1 from procedure schmea2.proc2 using dblink. 
For certain cases schema1.proc1 returns the error

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

however, when i try to execute it with the same input arguments using pl/sql, it works properly.

please help me in resolving the error.

code:

```
var1 VARCHAR2(10),
var2 VARCHAR2(25),
var3 VARCHAR2(75),
var4 VARCHAR2(200)

begin
 pkg1.getdetails@dbLINK1(var1, var2, var3,var4);
end

create or replace package body pkg1 as
 procedure getdetails (var1 in varchar2, var2 out varchar2, var3 out varchar2, var4 out varchar2) as
  v_var2 varchar2(100);
  v_var3 varchar2(200);

 begin
  select col2,col3  into v_var2, v_var3
  from table1 where col1 = var1;

  var2 := substr(v_var2,1,25);
  var3 := substr(v_var3,1,75);

exception when others then
 var4 := substr(sqlerrm,1,200);
end;
```

end;

Comment: Please show the definition of the stored procedure.

Comment: Hi Gordon,updated code snippet

Comment: What are the charactersets of the two databases? And what are the 'certain circumstances' - certain lengths of values that should be returned, perhaps?

Comment: Apparently there was an issue in deployment, where the changes in one schema has been implemented  and the other was not which has caused the issue. Thanks all for your help and time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

There is the possibility that the error is here:

```
select col2, col3 into v_var2, v_var3
from table1
where col1 = var1;
```

Perhaps `col2` and `col3` can be longer than 100/200 characters.

You might go for:

```
select substr(col2, 1, 25), substr(col3, 1, 75) into var2, var3
from table1
where col1 = var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was an issue in deployment, where the changes in one schema has been implemented and the other was not which has caused the issue.

Thanks all for your help and time.